# Store and retrieve Japanese characters in mySQL database in Spring MVC based application

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, character-encoding, internationalization

I am building one web application using:

- SPRING MVC
- SPRING SECURITY
- HIBERNATE
- mySQL

I want to add internationalization support for Japanese language in my app.

To display label and messages from properties file in japanese language , I have made use of Spring Locale Interceptor and its working fine.

What I need , I want to store Japanese characters in Database **(not in Unicode)** from user inputs and want to display on page.

Also , when i enters Japanese characters in form , in POJO, it is automatically converted in unicode, how can i disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

To store or read characters in the database with explicitly specified encoding, use `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding` properties in your JDBC URL. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

In the 2nd question, do you mean that you want to use `byte[]` instead of `java.lang.String` when you treat input strings? I think you can do it, but I can not recommend it.